# How can I limit the number of returned Google search results in this C# program?

Tags: c#, google-api

I just want to return four results with the following C# snippet.  How can I accomplish this?  I know I could probably just parse the returned results, but I'd rather just grab only four to begin with, if that's possible.

```
var searchTerm = "pizza boxes";
        using (var web = new WebClient())
        {
            web.Headers.Add("Referrer", "http://localhost:49360/");
            var result = web.DownloadString(String.Format(
                   "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q={0}",
                   searchTerm));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_intro_fonje) it looks like you could just put

```
rsz=4
```

in the URL.

Note that although I work for Google, I have no experience in these APIs, and this answer should be seen as a *personal* one, and not associated with Google :)

(I further note that the API has been deprecated. Have you looked at moving to the [custom search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) instead?)

Comment: Aww! Deprecated?!?  Heh, looks like I'll be checking out the custom search API at the link you provided.  Thanks, Mr. Skeet!  I appreciate it!

Comment: @Altar: I'm not particularly surprised after 3 years. I'm not sure whether that service even exists any more.

Comment: @JonSkeet - link to the NEW api (custom search API) is broken!

Comment: @Altar: Well it was new *3 years ago*. Again, I'm not sure whether it even exists any more.

Comment: @JonSkeet - so even the 'new' Custom Search API is now deprecated? Boy, google do changes technologies a lot.

Comment: @Altar: Again, I want to emphasize *3 years ago*. I don't know how long ago the "custom search API" was started, or when it was removed, but 3 years is a pretty long time in technology.

Answer (score 1):

Think you have two parameters you can set:

```
start=1;
rsz='large'
```

The `rsz` value can set to `small` or `large`, small will fetch 4 results and large will fetch 8 results.

`start` value can be set as any other integer to start from that particular row.

Comment: Thanks, Martin!  I just saw those values on the first link that Mr. Skeet (above) linked in his answer.  I appreciate it!

Comment: Guess I was too late, but looks like rsz only takes small/large, not an integer. But the custom search API is much cleaner.