# How to get 50 results in a single Google Search result page?

Tags: c#, search

I am making a c# application. It needs to get 50 results in a single page, but I don't know how to make it happen.

Here is my code to get the Google search results

```
string querrystring="Hello";
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
string googlepage = wb.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + querrystring);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following query string parameter:

```
&num=50

http://www.google.com/search?q=tonneau&hl=en&biw=1148&bih=729&num=50&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=
```

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=tonneau - this should work without any other parameters, are you logged into Google? If so, your personal Google Search settings might be overriding the query string parameters. For instance, this parameter will NOT work when Google Instant Search is enabled.

Comment: @rkaregaran try this post the answer from mr jon skeet may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212408/how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-returned-google-search-results-in-this-c-program

Comment: You have to go into the Search Settings and disable "Google Instant" here: http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en - regardless of whether you're logged in or not (Google Instant is on by default for _all_ users.

Comment: Ok I got it when I tried programatically.do you know what are these: biw,bih,lr,ft?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the (deprecated) [Google Web Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/) or the new [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) to query for the results.

Comment: No I need to get it in web because if I want to get results from places then simply I can add tbm=plcs at the end of search tag instead of using places api,

Comment: The API is much more effective, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, but I'd like to show up another possibility: You can use the &start= parameter with a for loop. Example:

Page 1 - google.com/search?q=whatever&start=0

Page 2 - google.com/search?q=whatever&start=10

and so on.